# View Powershell custom type formatting definitions

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

When I have an object using custom type formatting, what's the easiest way to find and view the definition for it?

For example, the type `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]` has a custom format defined in the default powershell installation directory. It's pretty long, but I'm really only interested in getting any `ScriptBlock` items running for a specific type - example fields from this definition:

```xml
<!-- C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Registry.format.ps1xml -->
<ScriptBlock>$_.PSParentPath.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::", "")</ScriptBlock>
<TypeName>Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey</TypeName>
<ScriptBlock>
    $result = (Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $_.PSPath |
            Select * -Exclude PSPath,PSParentPath,PSChildName,PSDrive,PsProvider |
            Format-List | Out-String | Sort).Trim()
    $result = $result.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($result.Length, 5000) )
    if($result.Length -eq 5000) { $result += "..." }
    $result
</ScriptBlock>
```

Is there a way I can see if a specific type has a custom format, and where it's defined at? I explored around with the type's properties and such - hoping I could see some reference to the module or whatever loads the types:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey].Module

FullyQualifiedName : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll
Name               : mscorlib.dll
```

I happen to know that this is loaded from the PSSnapin instead of a module, and I can see it has a Formats property listing the format xml files:

```sh
Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.PowerShell.Core | fl Name,ModuleName,Formats


Name       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
ModuleName : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll
Formats    : {Certificate.format.ps1xml, DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml, 
             FileSystem.format.ps1xml, Help.format.ps1xml...}
```

But I'm not sure how I could discover this without knowing about it beforehand, and I would still need to open the files to see if they contain the type name.

Answer (score 1):

I did eventually find `Get-FormatData` via [about_Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.1), which returns an object with the formatting settings (if there are any) when given a type:

```
$FormatData = Get-FormatData -PowerShellVersion ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion) -TypeName 'Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey'
$FormatData.FormatViewDefinition.Control.Rows.Columns.DisplayEntry.Value

#Returns:
  $result = (Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $_.PSPath |
      Select * -Exclude PSPath,PSParentPath,PSChildName,PSDrive,PsProvider |
      Format-List | Out-String | Sort).Trim()
  $result = $result.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($result.Length, 5000) )
  if($result.Length -eq 5000) { $result += "..." }
  $result
```

It doesn't seem to contain the path to the ps1xml file, but I can `Export-FormatData` to create a copy somewhere.